# Reload the page php without fill the text boxes with old data (PHP)

Tags: php, html

( Action after the page reloading ).

I want if the user click on "Reload or refresh the page (f5), all textboxes which is in my form to become empty.

Right now, if I refresh the page, still some data entry from my previous visit filled (by default) into textboxes.

How I can archive this ?

Comment: Could you add more information, such as adding the form with the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the inputs value on page load.

```
  function init() {
        // Clear forms here
        document.getElementById("user").value = "";
    }
    window.onload = init;
```

Or clear all form values

```
$(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
```

Comment: I need it to be done once the user click on refresh, what you mentioned, is it a function need to be re-call ?

Comment: I I create a function with name (init) as you mentioned, where I need to paste the  (window.onload = init;)

Comment: No, if you place it in a window.onload function it will fire once the user loads the webpage. So also when the user refreshes the webpage.

Comment: Place it between the script tags at the bottom of your file. For more information see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `autocomplete="off"` in the inputs of the form

```
<form>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" />
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```